# Target Android API 29 on Delphi 10.3.3

Tags: android, delphi, android-manifest, firemonkey

I have the Delphi 10.3.3, and I have some apps on Google Play that I update frequently. The case is that on Nov 2, I will have to target API 29 on my apps.

The thing is that Delphi 10.3.3 does not do this automatically. So this is the list of things I think I have to do and I do not know how to do them:

- Download the new API 29 with the Android SDK Manager of the Delphi (which I don't find)
- Edit the SDK Manager configuration to install well the API 29
- Edit the Android Manifest file to target API 29

The case is that I do not know how to edit the AndroidManifest file through Delphi because I think I need to do some steps before. (I need to know how to edit it, I do not find this info anywhere)

I need to install the API 29, configure it well on Delphi, and edit AndroidManifest.xml in Delphi.

I'll appreciate your answers. I need help :-)

Comment: Ask also in Embarcadero forum.

Comment: The Android AVD Manager can be accessed via the Start Menu, under Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.3. If you installed Android support when you installed the IDE, the installer puts it there. As far as your question, your first effort should be to read the Delphi documentation, as this topic is covered there in detail. We're not meant to be a substitute for doing your own research.

Comment: Also, you asked this exact same question on Sept 3 (which I just closed as a duplicate of this one). It is inappropriate to post the same question more than once. Please visit the [help] to find out how to properly deal with your question not getting answers or when they've been closed.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't find the AVD manager. But I think I was able to add the API 29 with the SDK Manager that I found doing research on ProgramFiles.

Comment: @KenWhite I did research. My last option is to ask here, but because I did not found anything helpfully, I asked here. I am not asking you to do my work, only a little help. But thank you though.

Comment: @KenWhite thank you for closing my other question. I didn't know how to close the question or how to get answers. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

> I need to install the API 29, configure it well on Delphi, and edit AndroidManifest.xml in Delphi.

Did you read Embarcadero's documentation yet?

[Adding an Android SDK](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Adding_an_Android_SDK)

[Android Application Manifest File (AndroidManifest.xml)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Android_Application_Manifest_File_(AndroidManifest.xml))

[Customizing Your AndroidManifest.xml File](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Preparing_an_Android_Application_for_Deployment#Customizing_Your_AndroidManifest.xml_File)

Comment: Thank you. Now I've found how to change the TargetSdk from android manifest with the AndroidManifest.template.xml

Comment: But now the thing I do not understand is the first link, to add the SDK. I downloaded successfully the SDK29, and On Delphi >> Tools >> Options >> Deployment >> SDK Manager, I can not add another SDK because the Android SDK 25.2.5 says I already have it. Do you think that changing the zipAlign location, the AAPT location and the SDK API-Level Location then I will be able to just change the target SDK on Android Manifest to 29? I mean , I installed the API 29, but now probably I have to change the route of the SDK on Delphi.

Comment: Because, I think the SDK version is different than the API version, isn't it?

Comment: Probably https://delphiworlds.com/2018/05/targeting-android-8-and-higher/ the first part of this tutorial is the thing I must do? And then change the AndroidManifest.template.xml?

Comment: @Remy. The Embarcadero documentation is severely lacking appropriate detail for updating RAD Studio to use a different Android SDK. It generally requires you to manually change the various folder properties for the SDK, NDK and Java. The https://delphiworlds.com/2020/09/manual-android-sdk-ndk-install-delphi/ article is better than anything Embarcadero released.

Comment: There is an EnvOptions.proj file in C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\20.0 that contains the DefaultPlatformSDK to be used for Android64 and Android. This points to two SDK files in the same folder called AndroidSDK25.2.5_64bit.sdk and AndroidSDK25.2.5_32bit.sdk. Those files contain all the folder properties, and more importantly, the display name and version information for the profile, which cannot be changed through the IDE. Once you have made the necessary changes to point the profiles to the 29 API SDK, you can rename the files and the details to have the right version info.