# How to install latest Android SDK with Delphi SDK Manager?

Tags: android, delphi, android-sdk-manager

I am using Delphi 10.4 and I would like to install Android 31 API SDK. Delphi has its own SDK manager, available e.g. from 'Options - Deployment - SDK Manager'. And this SDK Manager has option 'Add...' 'Add a New SDK' - 'Select an SDK version' - 'Add New...'.

So far everything is fine. But 'Add New...' opens 'Create a new Android SDK' which does not provide options for downloading and installing SDKs, it just requires to the directories to an already installed SDK. It also suggests, that 'Android SDK Base path' could be '/Documents/Embarcader/Studio/21.0/CatalogRepository/AndroidSDK-2525'.

So, this suggests, that I should manually downaload Android SDK (specific API level) in unzip/install into the CatalogRepository for the specific Delphi version.

The strange thing is that Google/Android does not provide the option to download specific, standalone SDK. Android, instead, suggests to download its own SDK Manager tools https://developer.android.com/studio/#command-tools and then do all the SDK management from that tool. While I can expect that this command line tool smoothly integrates with Android Studio, there is not suggestion that it integrates with Delphi SDK Manager.

I am aware of [Target Android API 29 on Delphi 10.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63835416/target-android-api-29-on-delphi-10-3-3) and https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Adding_an_Android_SDK, there is no suggestion how can I get SDK of specific API level to my computer.

So - how to get SDK of specific API level to my computer ready to be used by Delphi SDK manager.

**Additional Information**: I am reading https://delphiworlds.com/2020/09/manual-android-sdk-ndk-install-delphi/ and http://delphi.org/2019/06/manually-installing-android-sdk-ndk-and-java-for-firemonkey-development/ and they may give the answers. Delphi has it own peculiarities.

Comment: Download command line tools and then use sdkmanager tool to download the SDK  https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager